# Xterm, Vim, LXLE

Tags: linux, vim, xterm

My problem is within Vim, when I type something that returns an error the box that returns the error message at the bottom of the window shows up as solid white. 
After researching nonstop I haven't been able to find this problem before, one main part of it is I don't know the technical name for this area of the vim window. I have gotten to the point where I believe it's a conflict between the xterm color scheme and vim. If anyone has had this experience or has information that could help that would be great.

I am using the distro LXLE which comes with Xterm and an already populated Xresources file by default.

Comment: What is your `$TERM`?

Comment: The default terminal for LXLE isn't *xterm* but rather one of the VTE-wrappers.  In that case, X-resources is unused.   `TERM` is irrelevant; what is *relevant* is how the colors are set up.

Answer (score 0):

That area at the bottom where error messages appear is the *command-line*. Vim uses predefined *highlighting groups* for various output. The error messages use `ErrorMsg` (cp. `:help hl-ErrorMsg`).

If you do `:hi ErrorMsg`, the problem should be reproducible. Can can either switch to a different colorscheme (check the full `:hi` output for any other bad color combinations), or, if the error message is the only problem, modify the highlight group, like this:

```
:hi ErrorMsg cterm=... ctermfg=... ctermbg=...
```

See `:help highlight-term` for an explanation. To make that permanent, put the above command below the `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`.

All of this assumes that your terminal is correctly set up; i.e. `$TERM` has a correct value and the number of colors available (`:set t_Co?`) is correct.